# I'm getting "Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'tailwindcss' does not exist in type 'NuxtConfig'

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

In my nuxt.config.ts file, I would want to create a custom tailwind css path. However I keep getting this error. [image]

How should i create the custom tailwind css path in my nuxt.config.ts file?

Comment: Do you use typescript? If not, you can disable it. Otherwise, you'll need to import types for it.

Answer (score 0):

To config a custom path with tailwind, you must configure it in `tailwind.config.js` :

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./components/**/*.{js,vue,ts}",
    "./layouts/**/*.vue",
    "./pages/**/*.vue",
    "./plugins/**/*.{js,ts}",
    "./nuxt.config.{js,ts}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Please follow [tailwind doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nuxtjs) to use it with Nuxt